# How to get the UserName of the user making the call to the API?

Tags: authentication, identity, single-page-application, asp.net-web-api2

**Tech**: ASP.Net Web API 2 Authentication.

**IDE**: I am using the SPA template in Visual Studio 2013.

**Story**: I have added a controller with one Get method (see code) and executed a test in order to print “System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name” . **The end game is to find the Identity of the client calling to the API.**

**Question**: Why is the identity showing empty? Is it related to the fact the call is served on a  different thread? Is the token (that the client received upon login) a part of the request and being used for authentication?

I tried to keep it short for clarity so please let me know if you need more info.

```
public class abcController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/abc
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] 
        { System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name.ToString(), 
          "My Try" 
        };
    }
```

---

Ok, I found a workaround (not a solution). Basically, remove this line “config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();”.
http://forums.asp.net/p/1944393/5594350.aspx?Re+Web+API+2+how+do+I+find+the+identity+of+an+authenticated+user+

---

Comment: What type of authentication do you have configured in your Startup.Auth.cs class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the javascript side, in the webapi calls you'll want to make sure you call their getSecurityHeaders function in the app.datamodel.js, like this (after they have logged in of course):

```
    var getabc = function () {
        return $.ajax("api/abc", {
            type: "GET",
            headers: getSecurityHeaders()
        });
    };
```

If you don't call their getSecurityHeaders() function, the Identity will be null.

For completeness, here is that function:

```
function getSecurityHeaders() {
        var accessToken = sessionStorage["accessToken"] || localStorage["accessToken"];

        if (accessToken) {
            return { "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken };
        }

        return {};
    }
```

Comment: Hi Jason, This sounds exactly like what I was looking for. I will test it and check back to update. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the identity from the HttpRequestMessage object and not from the current thread:

```
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[]  
        { 
            this.Request.GetRequestContext().Principal.Identity.Name
        };
    }
```

The static methods HttpContext are no longer available in Web Api 2.

Comment: grennis, thanks for the quick reply. A small example will be highly appreciated.

Comment: No luck. Still empty.

Comment: Also, I did some testing and found out the following:
1. Upon successful registration\login, the user gets a token
2. For some reason, subsequent request doesn't convey this token back to the server
Shouldn't the token be a part of the user’s request?

Comment: Yes it should send a cookie back with an identifier that asp.net uses to associate the client to a user.

Comment: No luck so far. The SPA template is using OAuth with a bearer token and OWIN, which is more correct in Web API world (Instead of using a cookie). Thanks for the follow up @grennis.

Comment: Which SPA template are you using? I see a bunch on http://www.asp.net/single-page-application/overview/templates. I would like to know the answer to this also. I will help look into it.

Comment: The SPA template ships with VS 2013 (i.e. built in. Not in the link above). All my testing are on the clean Single Page App (for simplicity).

Comment: I have MSDN VS 2013 Premium and I do not have any such template installed with VS.

Comment: Hi @grennis, please check this link. This is the SPA template I am using: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/working-with-spa-template-in-visual-studio-2013-rc/. This article introduces ASP.NET Web Applications using the Single Page Application project template newly defined in the Visual Studio 2013 Release Candidate version (I am using the GA not the RC).

Comment: I'm not sure if the workaround you found does qualify as a solution or not. Using only bearer authentication may not be able to identify a "user" since an API call is quite possibly from another application, not a user. The host authentication may be required for user identity name. Interesting...